# android webview error Page not found

Tags: android, html, webview, assets

I use webVIew read local HTML.
HTML storage location
**Project for asset**

Some phones can be successfully used(samsung...)
Some phones can not(HTC nexus...)

Here is my code

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private WebView wvBrowser; 

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        findViews();
    }

    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if (wvBrowser.canGoBack() && event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK && event.getRepeatCount() == 0) {
            wvBrowser.goBack();
            return true;
        }

        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }

    private void findViews() {
        wvBrowser = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.Browser);

        //wvBrowser.loadUrl(getString(R.string.googleUrl));

        wvBrowser.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
        wvBrowser.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        wvBrowser.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/ts.htm");      
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Just wanted to add one more answer. Someone might find my suggestion helpful. 
You need to add uses-permission in your AndroidManifest.xml. I got similar error fixed by adding this line

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this link it will help you better  [webview](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html)

Attach a WebViewClient to your WebView, where you override onReceivedError()

```
webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
       public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {

       }
     });
```